# Firewall/iptables rules for GlusterFS

Tags: security, iptables, firewall, glusterfs

A great pleasure would be to know which exact iptables rules to use for securing GlusterFS 3.4.2 (with Debian Wheezy) in shared environment. I'm running some dedicated servers at ISP. There are two servers (named `lb01` and `lb02`) acting as nodes and clients the same time. My actual rules look like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -d localhost -p tcp --dport 111 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d localhost -p udp --dport 111 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d localhost -p tcp --dport 24007:24020 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s lb01 -p tcp --dport 24007:24008 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s lb01 -p tcp --dport 49152:49170 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s lb02 -p tcp --dport 24007:24008 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s lb02 -p tcp --dport 49152:49170 -j ACCEPT
```

Is that enough or too much? Are there opinions? I want to secure GlusterFS as much as possible to prevent access from other servers. (I know the presence of `gluster volume set <VOL> auth.allow` but I want to secure system in an earlier stage.)

Comment: Do you use Gluster NFS service ? How many bricks for every volume do you have ?

Comment: No, NFS is not used. There is one brick per volume and all volumes are replicated. I use GlusterFS to have millions of assets replicated in nearly realtime between two active web servers.

Comment: `Is that enough ?` Actually does it work like expected ? `one brick per volume` So how many bricks/volumes do you have (that is for `or too much?`) ?

Answer (score -2):

do like this

`iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT`

allow LAN machine access

Comment: Just because this might be acceptable/working in your environment it does not  mean it would also work elsewhere. OP wants a restriction, not a blanket "allow everything" and you don't even know about their network layout.

Comment: Well,you are right.

Comment: "apt-get remove iptables" is even easier :)